Centered 9-gonal numbers vs Concentric 9-gonal numbers.How does their visual representation differ?
The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) contains two distinct sequences involving 9-sided polygons:

A060544: Centered 9-gonal numbers (also known as nonagonal or enneagonal numbers)
These represent every third triangular number, starting with a(1)=1
https://oeis.org/A060544
A195042: Concentric 9-gonal numbers
https://oeis.org/A195042

What are the key geometric differences in how these two types of 9-gonal patterns are drawn or constructed? How does their visual representation differ?
